# How to Implement React.Js in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, react, headless, react-js

How to Implement **React.Js** in Magento 2?

Many of sites in now days using React Js in frontend.

How to start/configure with React in Magento 2?

Comment: Follow this URL - https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2 - How to integrate ReactJS  with Magento 2 frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check following:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElZ5UtTXpzQ - It is a talk on Integrating a ReactJS frontend in Magento 2
2. https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2 - This is a simple module which explains how to add and use React Components with Magento 2

Comment: I was provided with third-party react.js theme build.How to integrate it with magento 2??

Answer (score 2):

You can use Progressive Web App (PWA) in Magento 2. It uses react js.

PWA official tutorial [link](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/tutorials/)

**Minimum Requirements:**

- Basic knowledge of [React](https://reactjs.org/)
- [NodeJS >=10.14.1 LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- [Yarn >=1.13.0](https://yarnpkg.com/)

Comment: I was provided with third-party react.js theme build.How to integrate it with magento 2??

Answer (score 2):

You can start with PWA studio, since their documentation is quite extensive. [PWA studio repository](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio)

You can also learn from third party Magento 2 React.js PWA storefronts:

[Deity falcon](https://demo.deity.io/). Built with React (commercial)
[GraphCommerce](https://www.graphcommerce.org/). Built with React (open source)
[ScandiPWA](https://scandipwa.com/). Built with React (open source)